# Unable locate element in selenium using Xpath in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

i tried below code in chrome it working fine ,but same thing is not working in Internet explorer saying no such element error.
Not sure if internet explorer has any issue handing them . I am using windows 10 OS and internet explorer comes with it.
 In Internet explorer i can able to login with selenium after the landing page when i want to click new business link its not working,
but the same code works fine in chrome. Is there any reason for this ?
i am using selenium 2.52 java and same IEdriver as well

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'menuopt=PolicyType&TransTyp=NB')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='New Business - Rate']/ancestor::a")).click();
driver.findelement(By.cssselector(a[href*='TransTyp=NBS'])).click ();
```

`<a href="XXXX.asp?WCI=XXXX_Process&amp;CacheID=123351730222025121&amp;menuopt=Policy&amp;TransTyp=NB">
   <strong><font face="Arial" color="Navy">New Business - Rate</font></strong>
</a>`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this one...

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'New Business - Rate')]")).click()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11454173)

Comment: @MartinZabel how do you know it doesnt provide an answer? The way he is identifying the element is shaky. I offered a more stable way to identify that may work in IE.. Thanks for the review.

Comment: Then do not write it like a question, please.

Comment: @Tree55Topz  Sorry it didnt workout either, got same error Unable to find element with Xpath .. i am using IE 11,as i told earlier same code works in chrome